# Strange behavior of \addfontfeature{FakeBold=...}. No utf8 output!

Tags: fontspec

I tried to use FakeBold feature of fontspec in a simple text that mix Latin letters  with Greek inside the same word. My problem is that  the output seems Utf8 but actually it is not!   I noticed that when I tried to copy and paste the output of following code  in a text editor(TeXworks) then 1) Some characters are in ? 2)there is no space between the first word Γεννaται(in bold) and the second one

(in my case the output is  ΓεννaταιΓεννaται Γενν?ται)

Could you please explain me this strange behavior?

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article} 
        \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
        \usepackage{polyglossia}
        \setmainlanguage{greek} 
        \setmainfont{Arial}
        \begin{document}
        \addfontfeature{FakeBold=2}Γεννaται\addfontfeature{FakeBold=0} Γεννaται Γεννάται
        \end{document}
```

Notes: Each of the above lines are written in different lines in TeXworks. I used MikTeX and XeLaTeX engine.

Comment: Why not using `\textbf{Γεννaται} Γεννaται Γεννάται`?

Comment: I see no problem. Spaces can always disappear - this depends on the pdf viewer. Glyphs can disappear if the font you are using doesn't contain them. Btw: pdf doesn't contain utf8.

Comment: @egreg Sometimes, it is vary usefull to have different boldness in the text

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer Have you tried to copy paste this simlpe output? I used very simple glyphs and the output seems ok. But the problem starts when I try to copy -paste the output!

Comment: @kornaros No, it wouldn't be.

Comment: @everybody I tried the same code and with many pdf viewers in win7 and win10. I always take ? or some strange utf characters e.g. ΓεννaταιΓεννaται ΓεννȐται. I wonder if other users of MikTeX/fontspec have the same problem with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\addfontfeatures{...}` gobbles spaces following it, which is a good thing in general; use

```
\addfontfeature{FakeBold=2}Γεννaται\addfontfeature{FakeBold=0}\ Γεννaται Γεννάται
```

if you really want to use this awkward style. In general, `\addfontfeatures` should be used sparingly and (almost) never in a document. Moreover, since it respects grouping, doing

```
{\addfontfeature{FakeBold=2}Γεννaται} Γεννaται Γεννάται
```

would be easier.

However, this should better be

```
\textbf{Γεννaται} Γεννaται Γεννάται
```

All examples typeset the same

[image]

If your font doesn't have boldface, define it in the font setup. I'll make an example with EB Garamond

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]

\begin{document}

\textbf{Γεννaται} Γεννaται Γεννάται

\end{document}
```

[image]

About the `?`, I believe it's a problem of copy-pasting, dependent on the operating system.